# trying to FineTune restNet50 mode Problem

Tags: python, keras

Hope someone can help me, I been looking at this for hours...

no matter what batch_size I use, 8,12,16,24 I get the same error with a different ending,

if I increase the batch size to 32, it gives me a GPU out of memory, so I lower it and then I get this error

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(380,380,3), include_top=False)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

x = base_model.output
predicted = Dense(2,activation ='sigmoid')(x)

model_pretrain = models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predicted)

model_pretrain.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0002),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
batch_size=8

history=model_pretrain.fit(x_train, Y_train,
                           verbose=1,
                           batch_size=8,  
                           epochs=3,
                           use_multiprocessing=True,
                           workers=10 )
--------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [8] vs. [8,12,12]
     [[{{node metrics_2/acc/Equal}}]]
     [[loss_1/mul/_7573]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [8] vs. [8,12,12]
     [[{{node metrics_2/acc/Equal}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
-----------------------------------------------------------------
if I se batch_size of 24 
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [24] vs. [24,12,12]
     [[{{node metrics_2/acc/Equal}}]]
     [[loss_1/mul/_7573]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [24] vs. [24,12,12]
     [[{{node metrics_2/acc/Equal}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in this line of code:  `Dense(2,activation ='sigmoid')`.

You cannot use `Dense` layer with 2 neurons and `sigmoid` activation.

First of all, ensure that all your input data is fed accordingly.

Second of all, in order for your code to work,

change

`Dense(2,activation ='sigmoid')`

to

`Dense(2,activation ='softmax')` OR  `Dense(1,activation ='sigmoid')`.

But in order for one of these two solutions to work the data needs to be fed accordingly(you do not need to one-hot encode binary labels for example for `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid)`. But if you use `Dense(2,activation ='softmax')`, then your labels need to be one-hot encoded: e.g. [1,0] for class 1 and [0,1] for class 2.

Comment: Clain, thanks a lot for the response, I will try as soon as I can, and yes all my labels are 1,0.

Comment: I am 100% sure that if you don't have any other issues your code will work once you implement what I suggested.

Comment: If my suggestion solves your problem, please don't forget to accept and upvote.

Comment: Yes it answered my question to the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Timbus Calin, I was able to get it working with his suggestion.

Dense(2,activation ='softmax')

Comment: Thank you for the kind comment. Please accept my answer and upvote it. In this way, people know your problem is solved and the solution to it! I would really appreciate if you voted up.